# Speed up rsync by running multiple instances at once?

Tags: concurrency, ssh, rsync, file-transfer

I have to transfer a big directory to another server.

My problem is that i cannot use the full bandwidth that would be available, because one concurrent tcp stream does not get as fast.

Basically the functionality that any download manager nowadays supports.

Therefore I would like to do concurrent data streams.

However I cannot find a program that supports this, so I thought about just running multiple instances or rsync at once.

Is this a good idea or can you point me into the direction of a more suitable tool?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of another tool, but two rsync sessions in parallel would certainly be fine.

However, you'd need partition the directory carefully. Two rsyncs with identical parameters would be counter-productive, or just broken (potentially).

Also, watch out for SSH connection sharing. It's very useful for quick authentication, but I'm not sure if you don't end up sending all the data down the same TCP stream.

Comment: i think i will just write a quick script that grabs the file list from rsync -va --dry-run and then loops over it entry by entry and transfers every file with an individual rsync command in a sub process. i have key authentication set up so it will run without password authenticaiton...

Comment: Since you're after speed, you might find that carving it up into 100-file chunks, say, might outperform rsync on individual files? (I mean, there's a highish overhead to creating a new connection each time.) Also, if there are sub-directories that have to be created, there might be a race condition there? Finally, don't confuse SSH connection *sharing* with key authentication: the former only *pretends* to open a new link, while the second actually does.